# Websocket event fires but arrives very late to client

Tags: node.js, websocket

**Background**

A nodeJS server fires websocket messages in response to database changes. These messages are received on application web clients.

**Problem**

I see a 20 second delay from when the event is fired on the server to when it is received on the client. But not all users experience the problem. Only some. Server memory seems fine.

**Question**

Any thoughts about what could delay the arrival of a websocket message after it has already been fired?